# Calculating expectation of an integral involving brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm trying to calculate this:
$\mathbb{E} \left[\displaystyle \left(\int_0^t B_s^2 ds\right)^2\right]$, where $B_s$ is Brownian process with zero mean and variance $s$. I tried Ito isometry, but that's not useful here.

An idea would be calculating $\displaystyle \int_0^t B_s^2 ds$, raising to power 2 and then taking expectation, but I don't know how to calculate $\displaystyle \int_0^t B_s^2 ds$, because we can't use integration by part here.

Is there any hint?

Comment: Just that component (I believe) would look like : $E[\int_0^t B^2_s ds]^2= (\int_0^tE[ B^2_s] ds)^2=(\int_0^t s ds)^2 = \frac{t^4}{4}$ but that comes down to my interpretation of your parenthesis on the expectation value.

Comment: no we can't put the expectation inside the integral, because there is a power 2.

Comment: Just to clarify: $E[(\int_0^tB^2_s ds)^2]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
E\left(\int_0^t B^2_sds\times \int_0^t B^2_udu\right)
 &= 2E\left(\int_0^t \left(\int_0^uB^2_sds\right) B^2_udu\right) \\
 &= 2\int_0^t\left(\int_0^uE(B^2_sB^2_{u})\right)dsdu \\
 &= 2\int_0^t\left(\int_0^uE(B^2_s(B_{s}+B'_{u-s})^2\right)dsdu \\
 &=2\int_0^t\left(\int_0^uE(B^4_s+2B^3_sB'_{u-s}+B^2_sB'^2_{u-s})\right)dsdu\\
 &=2\int_0^t\left(\int_0^u(3s^2+0+s(u-s))\right)dsdu \\
 &=2\int_0^t\left(\int_0^u(2s^2+su)\right)dsdu \\
 &= \frac{7}{12}t^4.
\end{split}
$$